# Increasing via value in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm writing a 'personality type' quiz and want to assign values to choices that a user selects as they progress through the quiz. The idea is each response to a question will have a different numeric weight, which I'll tally as someone progresses through and ultimately completes the quiz. At the end, I'll use the tally to present one of a few different results.

At the moment, users are able to progress through the quiz but I can't get the numeric weight to work.

This is my approach in the code below:
- I am using countValue as my tally. It's set at 1 at the top of my JS.
- In each question within the quiz, there's a value titled addition that is assigned a number, like initial view of the quiz has addition: 0
- As the quiz progresses, there's a field for addition.
- At the bottom of the quiz is a function titled display_scenario in which I attempt to add the value of addition to countValue, but it's not working. I can see that it's not working because the console log gives me values of NaN for the values within the function.

So it seems like I'm not turning the addition value into an integer/number. I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried using parseInt() and Number() and had no luck.

The full code is on Codepen -  http://codepen.io/msummers40/pen/EKJQmN - but the key JavaScript/jQuery is below. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
//establishing counter for weighted answer
var countValue = 1;
console.log(countValue);
// var additionInt = 1;
// console.log(additionInt);

// JSON for personality quiz
// Contains the story, paths and variable to weight answers
var story = {
    intro: {
        prompt: 'Welcome message. Let\'s get started.',
        quizImage: '<img id="quizImage" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/vc6gDdl4rHusE/giphy.gif"><br />',
        options: [{
            name: 'get started',
            path: 'get_started',
            addition: 0,
        }]
    },

    get_started: {
        prompt: 'You need pancakes. What kind will you make: thin or fluffy?',
        quizImage: '<img id="quizImage" src="http://www.allgifs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/pancake.gif">',
        options: [{
            name: 'thin',
            path: 'thin',
            addition: '2'
        }, {
            name: 'fluffy (leading to thin temporarily)',
            path: 'thin',
            addition: '3'
        }]
    },

//THIN PANCAKE SECTION
    thin: {
        prompt: 'Yum. What do you do next?',
        quizImage: '<img id="quizImage" src="//media.giphy.com/media/2Mp7y2FkcW80M/giphy.gif">',
        options: [{
            name: 'pop out to get store-bought pancakes',
            path: 'result',
            addition: '2'
        }, {
            name: 'use a recipe',
            path: 'result',
            addition: '1'
        }]
    },

    result: {
        prompt: 'That is all I have for this example!',
        quizImage: '<img id="quizImage" src="http://www.technologytell.com/entertainment/files/2013/11/Leonardo-DiCaprio-Toast-Fireworks-Gif.gif">',
        options: [{
            name: 'Reset',
            path: 'intro' //RESET
        }]
    }
};



/* Chosen option is an object with properties {name, path} */


function display_scenario(chosen_option) {
    var option_name = chosen_option.name;
    var option_path = chosen_option.path;
    var additionInt = chosen_option.addition;
    additionInt = Number(additionInt);
    console.log(additionInt);
    countValue = (additionInt + countValue);
    console.log(countValue);
    var scenario = story[option_path];
```

Comment: object you pass into `display_scenario()` in `document.ready` in demo has no property `addition` so `var additionInt = chosen_option.addition;` will be undefined

Comment: `console.log(chosen_option.addition)` is _undefined_ because you are passing `chosen_option` as `{ name: null, path: 'intro' }`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'd overlooked that final function - I updated that and tidied things up here and there and it's now working. http://codepen.io/msummers40/pen/JXVapo?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double check that your additionInt is not undefined before incrementing  the countValue (which is what's causing the problem at the intro).

```
function display_scenario(chosen_option) {
  var option_name = chosen_option.name;
  var option_path = chosen_option.path;
  var additionInt = chosen_option.addition;

  // Make sure all is well
  if(additionInt){
    countValue += additionInt;
  }

  var scenario = story[option_path];
  ...
  ...
}
```

As a side note, your addition property is already a number so you can remove the line `additionInt = Number(additionInt);`

Comment: This was really helpful - I clarified values in a function and tidied things up in the function that produced the running total value and it's now working. Thank you. http://codepen.io/msummers40/pen/JXVapo?editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

1) As the other answer states, your chosen option's addition property starts out undefined, so you can check for this and give it a default value in one line:

```
// with default value using ||
var additionInt = +chosen_option.addition || 0;

// or with ternary operator
var additionInt = !chosen_option.addition ? 0 : +chosen_option.addition;
```

Then augment `countValue`:

```
countValue += additionInt;
```

2) The `+` operator in the first couple of lines above will coerce the `option.addition` value to a number, but you should be consistent with your `addition` values one way or the other. You currently have the first as a number and the rest strings.

3) Below the section you duplicated here from the codepen, you have:

```
jQuery('<p>').html(countValue).appendTo('#countValueHere');
```

But you do not have an element with that `id` in your html. I assume you meant `#runningTotalHere`.

Comment: This was really helpful @bennett-adams - I fixed that item in your point no 3. I clarified values in a function and tidied things up in the function that produced the running total value and it's now working. Thank you. http://codepen.io/msummers40/pen/JXVapo?editors=0010